# Web page's semantic elements

Tags: css, html5

I request a review of the following web page, especially on the use of semantic elements:

https://jsfiddle.net/SSteven/qt9d2sfw/

The HTML5 code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Semantic page</title>

    <meta name="viewport" 
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
      *
      {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body
      {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .clearfix::after
      {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
      }

      .img-container
      {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;     /* 2 boxes */
        padding: 10px;  /* space between the images */
      }

      nav
      {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: navy;
      }

      nav a
      {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      nav a:hover
      {
        background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 35%);
      }

      nav a.active
      {
        color: navy;
        background-color: white;
      }

      .column
      {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
      }

      #sidenav
      {
        width: 20%;
      }

      #sidenav ul
      {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #sidenav li a
      {
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        display: block;
        padding: 8px;
        background-color: hsl(209, 70%, 90%);
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #444;
      }

      #sidenav li a:hover
      {
        background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
        color: white;
      }

      #sidenav li a.active
      {
        background-color: #008CBA;
        color: white;
      }

      main
      {
        width: 80%;
      }

      table, th, td
      {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      th, td
      {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      footer
      {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #aaa;
        padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
        text-align: center;
      }

      /* Use a media query to add a break point at 800px: */
      @media screen and (max-width: 800px)
      {
        nav li, #sidenav, main
        {
          /* The width is 100%, when the viewport is 800px or smaller */
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="clearfix">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://www.company.com/Images/Logo.jpg"
             alt="[Company logo]"
             style="width: 100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://www.company.com/Images/Office.jpg"
             alt="[Company Office]"
             style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </header>

    <nav>
      <a href="#AboutUs" class="active">ABOUT US</a>
      <a href="#Expertise">EXPERTISE</a>
      <a href="#Careers">CAREERS</a>
      <a href="#ContactUs">CONTACT US</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <aside class="column" 
             id="sidenav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#WhatWeDo">What we do</a></li>
          <li><a href="#WhyUs">Why Us?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Technologies">Technologies</a></li>
        </ul>
      </aside>

      <main class="column">
        <article>
          <h1>ABOUT THE COMPANY</h1>

          <section id="WhatWeDo">
            <h2>What we do</h2>

            <p>
              blah blah blah ...
            </p>

            <br><hr>
          </section>

          <section id="WhyUs">
            <h2>Why Us?</h2>

              <p>More blah ...</p>

            <br><hr>
          </section>

          <section id="Technologies">
            <h2>Technologies</h2>

            <p>Still more blah ...</p>
          </section>
        </article>
      </main>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <a href = "Terms.html">Terms</a> | 
      <a href = "Privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> | 
      <a href = "TrademarksCopyrights.html">Trademarks &amp; Copyrights</a> | 
      <a href = "Sitemap.html">Sitemap</a>
      <br />
      All rights reserved.
    </footer>
  </body>
```

Specifically:

1) At the top, 2 images are supposed to be displayed. (Currently, their alt text is displayed.) I have treated this as the <**header**>. I have used "float: left" to display both images horizontally.

2) The top menu has been displayed in an <**nav**> element, which has been styled along with its sub-elements.

3) The "side menu" has been included in an <**aside**> element.
4) The <**main**> element contains an <**article**> element, which has the main content.

Both the "side menu" and the <**main**> element are floated horizontally.

5) Finally, there is a <**footer**> element.

Basically, I'd like to ask:
1) Is the use of the semantic elements appropriate?
2) Is their styling done correctly or is there a better way?
3) I have indented the HTML code. Does this conform to a best practice for markup languages?
4) Review of the CSS code is also requested. I have indented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Character encoding

As a good practice, the character encoding should be included  in the `head` section of the document before the `title` element:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SigmaCubes - Home</title>
```

> In order for all browsers to recognize a  declaration, it must be
>
> - Within the `<head>` element,
> - Before any elements that contain text, such as the `<title>` element, AND
> - Within the first 512 bytes of your document, including `DOCTYPE` and whitespace

<sup>From Google Code Archive [doctype-mirror - MetaCharsetAttribute.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doctype-mirror/wikis/MetaCharsetAttribute.wiki)</sup>

---

## Semantics

Semantics are always highly opinion-based. It depends heavily on the actual content and context. This makes it hard to review the part inside `main`. The structure seems fine, but whether an `article` with nested `section` elements is the best fit, depends on the actual content.

The usage of `aside` is good, using it for a secondary navigation within the page.

### `nav`-element

I would say, you could use a list in the `nav`-element as well, like you did in the `aside`-element:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#AboutUs" class="active">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is also recommended by the Web Accessibility initiate:

> Convey the menu structure, typically by using a list. Such structural
>   information allows assistive technologies to announce the number of
>   items in the menu and provide corresponding navigation functionality.

<sup>From w3.org [Web Accessibility Tutorials: Menu Structure](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/structure/)</sup>

See also W3C [4.3.4. The nav element](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-nav-element) for more examples.

Same goes for the anchor elements in the `footer`.

### `hr`-elements

You're using `hr`-elements at the bottom of sections, which is not necessary:

> The hr element represents a paragraph-level thematic break.

<sup>From W3C [hr](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/hr.html)</sup>

Use CSS and `border-bottom` here.

### `br`-elements

Don't use `br`-elements to create distance between elements. Use CSS instead.

> The HTML `<br>` element produces a line break in text (carriage-return).
>   It is useful for writing a poem or an address, where the division of
>   lines is significant.

<sup>From MDN [`<br>`: The Line Break element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)</sup>

---

## `alt`-attributes

You use these `alt`-attributes on two images on the header:

> ```
> alt="[Company logo]"
> alt="[Company Office]"
> ```

First of all, you don't need to wrap the text into `[]`. Screen readers will read parentheses, brackets etc. so this can get annoying.

A logo don't need to have the word `logo` in its `alt`-attribute. The company name is just fine:

> It is common practice on the web to have the main site logo also link
>   to the site home page. Because this is fairly standard practice, providing
>   alternative text for the image, such as your company name (`alt="Acme Company`),
>   will usually suffice. Identifying the logo as actually being a logo
>   (`alt="Acme Company Logo"`) is not typically necessary. The content and
>   function is not "logo".

<sup>From WebAIM [Alternative Text: Logos](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#logos)</sup>

The alternative text `company office` is probably not descriptive enough *or* the image can have an empty `alt`-attribute, if it's just a [decorative image](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#decorative).

---

## Style

Try to be consistent:

> ```
> <a href="#WhatWeDo">What we do</a>
> <a href = "Sitemap.html">Sitemap</a>
> ```

… or:

> ```
> <br>
> <br />
> ```

---

Try to avoid ids in selectors in CSS. See CSSLint [Disallow IDs in selectors](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-IDs-in-selectors)
.

---

With just a couple of elements this might be readable:

> ```
> nav li, #sidenav, main
> ```

But at some point, it might get confusing. List the selectors like that:

```
nav li,
#sidenav,
main
```

Comment: the review points raised by you are excellent. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad, I could help you. @SSteven